# PHP ignores an invalid php.ini on the production server, but PHP refuses to work completely with the same INI on a Vagrant machine

Tags: php, webserver, ini

I have a stupid problem that is driving me nuts at the moment.

Our web apps are pretty small so we run them on a shared hosting environment. Therefore I don't have a lot of possibilities to change the server configuration. The only thing I can do is edit the php.ini that is used for our domain. Configuration of everything else is out of my reach.

That's why I wanted to set up a local Vagrant server that is as close to the production server as possible by installing the same PHP Version (almost! in Vagrant it is PHP 5.4.43, the production server however runs PHP 5.4.16) and using the same php.ini that is also used online.

Both servers are running Apache 2.4 and PHP via FastCGI using PHP-FPM.

However, when I try to start up PHP-FPM in the Vagrant machine with the php.ini that I have downloaded from the administration panel of our hosting provider, it exits with some fatal errors because some of the directives in the given php.ini are deprecated and have been removed. That made me wonder why the same php.ini refuses to work in Vagrant, but works online without problem.

As phpinfo() on the production server tells me, the downloaded ini file is the only php.ini that is being loaded. However, the file seems to be ignored and instead the default values are applied.

So I figure that particular ini file is a hangover from ancient times of our production server, and it is just as invalid on the production server as it is on my Vagrant machine - the error handling is just different! The production server handles the error gracefully, ignoring the invalid ini file silently, but my Vagrant machine refuses to work.

Ignoring the invalid ini file is obviously no solution to the root of the problem, but curiosity struck me. I thought this should be easy, but after googling for a while, I am still stuck. How and where can I configure PHP-FPM to ignore invalid ini files, instead of exiting with a fatal error?

Comment: What are you running your Vagrant Server on, i.e. the host OS

Comment: Its the hashicorp/precise64 box, hence Ubuntu Server 12.04 64bit, as I was told today by the support the production server runs Gentoo

Comment: As far as I understood, you are wondering why you get a php.ini Version missmatch if you try use Version 5.4.16 php.ini on 5.4.43?

Comment: No, the question is why the production server silently ignores the invalid ini file, whereas my Vagrant machine exits with fatal erros instead of ignoring the file ;)

Comment: So you are asking, why the production Server can handle the invalid file for his php version, while the Vagrant cannot handle invalid files of other versions? Or you just get PHP-Errors, which can be FATAL, too. Could you post the error message you receive?

Comment: The file is invalid on both servers, because it contains directives that have been removed in PHP 5.4, independent of the minor version. Therefore I get errors like this when running "sudo service php5-fpm restart" after copying the produciton ini to the Vagrant machine: "Restarting PHP5 FastCGI process manager ... Fatal error</b>:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />"

Comment: So the question is, why does the production server ignore the invalid ini file which produces these fatal errors and falls back to the default settings instead, whereas the Vagrant machine refuses to work entirely because of the fatal errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have been talking to our hoster's support team in the past days and I got an answer to how they achieved this behavior.

The answer is simple and at the same time frustrating: They are running a customized build of PHP. They patched PHP's error handling to ignore ini errors instead of throwing a fatal error and then compiled PHP themselves.

Consequently this is no standard PHP behavior and would be quite time-consuming to implement by oneself. It is definitely not worth the work for my purpose.